# Why is my ES6 having different exports (exports || exports.default + named) depending on the scope of the import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have this in a yargs script:

```js
  const pkg = require(join(argv.path, 'package.json'));
  const exported = require(join(argv.path, pkg.main));
  console.log(exported);
```

If i try to read this source within the yargs script package `pkg.main`:

```js
import SiteService, { SiteFunction } from 'site-service';

export const siteService = new SiteService('management', {
  id: 1000,
  othersIds: 1000,
});

export const siteFunction = new SiteFunction(siteService, {
  id: 1000,
  othersIds: 1000,
});

export default siteService;
```

The the value of exported is :

```js
{ siteService:
   SiteService {
     name: 'management',
     config: { id: 1000, othersIds: 1000 },
     siteFunctionList: [] },
  siteFunction:
   SiteFunction {
     siteService:
      SiteService {
        name: 'management',
        config: [Object],
        siteFunctionList: [] },
     config: { id: 1000, othersIds: 1000 } },
  default:
   SiteService {
     name: 'management',
     config: { id: 1000, othersIds: 1000 },
     siteFunctionList: [] } }
```

If i read the `pkg.main` of a different module with this content:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Resource from 'ra-core/lib/Resource';
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route';
import SiteService, { SiteFunction } from 'site-service';
const siteService = new SiteService('management', {
  id: 1000,
  otherIds: [1, 2],
});

import {
  UsersList,
  UsersCreate,
  UsersEdit,
  UsersShow,
} from './resources/users';

export const siteFunction = new SiteFunction(siteService, ({ pages, roles, permissions }) => [
  <Resource
    name="users"
    list={UsersList}
    edit={UsersEdit}
    create={UsersCreate}
    show={UsersShow}
  />,
], ({ pages, roles }) => [
], ({ pages, roles }) => [
  {
    name: 'management',
    redirect: true,
    from: '/management',
    to: '/',
    description: 'management',
  },
]);


export default siteFunction;
```

I have the following output

```js
SiteFunction {
  siteService:
   SiteService {
     name: 'management',
     config: { id: 1000, otherIds: [Array] },
     siteFunctionList: [] },
  config: [Function] }
```

Both project babel configuration in `babel.config.js`:

```
{
  only: [
    'src',
    'styleguide',
  ],
  comments: false,
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: false,
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    'babel-plugin-array-includes',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings',
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
      {
        legacy: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: [
        'babel-plugin-add-module-exports',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
      ],
    },
    test: {
      plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
        'babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node',
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

**In both case, the `pkg.main` imported was in ES6 syntax**, while the `yargs` script run was a ES5 transpiled file.

1. I believe this is not good, am I correct?
2. Where does the bug happen? Both projects have the same babel configuration.
3. Within my script, should I assume both cases can happen and should I support both?

Comment: Are your sure this is valid? `[  <Resource .../>, ]`

Comment: It is equivalent to `React.createElement`, yes it is valid and babel does not complain about jsx .

Comment: The second output seems incomplete. I can't tell what you think the difference is.

Comment: It is complete.

Comment: OK, so what exactly is that is wrong with the second one? It's unclear to me which value you are actually logging.

Comment: `exported` in the 1st highlight is equal to the default export `siteService` in the 2nd highlight

Comment: Are both packages use the same Babel version? How is the code transpiled? Have you looked at the files that Babel produces?

Comment: Same babel version, the code is transpiled using babel 7 and those modules. I have looked at the file that babel produce, but in this case, I am importing `src` so it is not transpiled file. That is the issue here.